# как передать переменной значение span class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу скрипт, вот кусок кода страницы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь в переменную temp передать значение 71 , но ничего не выходит. Какой можете подсказать способ для передачи этого значения?

```
  temp = +$('.pair-assets-select-label_colored')[0].innerText.slice(0,-1);
```

Comment: а что знавит ничего не выходит. Вы же посмотрели $('.pair-assets-select-label_colored') потом [0] потом innerText ? и что было на всех этих этапах?

Comment: @splash58 выводил temp в лог - выводится на всех этапах "NaN"

Comment: @splash58 какой php ? Это jquery

Comment: потому и спросил

Comment: и это тоже. тег php убрал

Comment: `let temp = parseFloat( $(".pair-assets-select-label_colored").eq(0).text() );` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME А вот это похоже работает, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Подправил ваш код: (с использованием jquery)

```
var res = $('span.pair-assets-select-label_colored').html().split('"');
var temp = res[1];
console.log(temp);

//temp = 71 :)
```

Без использования jquery (чистый javascript)

```
var res = document.getElementsByClassName('pair-assets-select-label_colored')[0].innerText.split('"');
var temp = res[1];
console.log(temp);

//temp = 71 :)
```

Comment: Сделал множество попыток - безуспешно.. выводит undefined.